# How to obtain the messageId or eventId of an event received via the Azure functions Event Hub Trigger?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an event hub trigger function linked to an event hub and I have set it up to receive events. The receive message works fine, and I am able to process the message when it is fired from the source, but recently I have started noticing duplicate events getting processed at the receiver.

How do I determine if these are unique events, with possibly the same payload or the same event processed multiple times? I have read about partition Ids, but seems like that only tells us which partition the message was picked up from. It is very possible that both the messages were picked up from the same partition at interval of some time.

My event hub trigger implementation looks something like follows:

```
[FunctionName("function-name")]
public async Task RunAsync(
[EventHubTrigger("az_eventhubname", 
    Connection = "connection-string-path", ConsumerGroup = "%AzureEventHubConsumerName%")] EventData ed, 
    ExecutionContext eCtx, PartitionContext PartitionContext)
{
    var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((ed).Body);
    // other tasks ...
}
```

I am able to bind both `ExecutionContext` and `PartitionContext` but none of them provide a message id or event id property, neither does `EventData`

- `EventData` provides only Sequence Number, Offset and Enque Time, in its `SystemProperties`.
- `PartitionContext` provides the partiton id and other info such as host id, offset, epoch, token, etc.
- `ExecutionContext` provides an invocation id

If Event Hub Triggers do not provide message ids or event ids, how can I distinguish between 2 messages having the same payload?

Comment: generally speaking, Event Hub processors - like your Azure Function - are expected handle at-least-once scenarios, i.e. it is expected to happen that messages might be delivered multiple times (usually this happens on scale out)

Comment: Sequence number, however, is a unique number - within a partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no strong concept of an event identity within Event Hubs; the responsibility of defining what makes an event unique falls to the application.  The closest approximation using just the Event Hubs service data would be the combination of the sequence number assigned to the event and the partition that it was read from.

Generally, it is encouraged that publishers and consumers coordinate on an item set in the `Properties` dictionary that is meaningful within the application context to identify the data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The current implementation of the source service, unfortunately, is beyond my control. Combining the sequence number, partition id and enque time, and maintaining an audit table seems like a good place to start. From what I know, the enque time is the UTC time when the event was put into the partition so that seems like fairly unique for each event in the partition, but does the sequence number repeat within a partition? For example, let's say after 100 or any n events for that matter will I see another event with sequence number 1 in the same partition?

Comment: Event Hubs guarantees that a sequence number is unique for a given partition.   It will, at some point, roll over to 0 but by the time it does the other instance will have aged past the retention period.  If you're audit records for duplicate detection are pruned using the retention period set for your Event Hub, the proposed approach should work.

Comment: One note on the enqueue time - it represents the moment when Event Hubs committed the event to a partition.  It does not necessarily match the time that a publisher received an ACK that an event was accepted.

Comment: @JesseSquire the function receives events as a batch, so in case of duplications, do we get the whole batch again or new batch can contains duplicate events?

Comment: There are no guarantees as to batch sizes nor whether a checkpoint was emitted that would advance by part of a batch.   You should expect events to individually be duplicated, they may or may not come in the same set that was previously read as a batch.